# How to listen to Skype for Business call events

Tags: events, office365, ms-office, skype, skype-for-business

I need to notify a backend server about Skype for Business call events. Calling the backend is not the problem, but listening to call events is. I thought about watching and parsing skype log files, but there seems to be no call information in the log files... And it would be an ugly solution anyway.

Is it possible to somehow listen to SfB call events and trigger custom actions?
I know there are various SfB SDKs, but none of them seem to offer a way to listen to these events...

I would like to be able to do something like this (pseudo code, I don't really care what language is used, but would prefer JavaScript):

```
skype.onCallIncoming(callInfo => {
    console.log(callInfo.user + ' is calling');
    // my custom action
});

skype.onCallAccepted(callInfo => {
    console.log('The call was accepted');
    // my custom action
});

skype.onCallEnded(callInfo => {
    console.log('The call was ended');
    // my custom action
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SfB does not provide any live "call events" that you can use in **ANY** SDK.

For live "calls", the best you can do (with little effort) is to subscribe to a users presence and hook off the "on a call" (on-the-phone) activity token busy status (this presence state is not guaranteed to be correct).  The problem with this is you can't really get "all" call events for everyone, since you can only subscribe to endpoints that you know about.  There are also problems with working with large scale subscriptions.  This can be done with most of the SDK's for Skype include [UCWA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/ucwa/unifiedcommunicationswebapi2_0).

Another option is to use the [CDR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skypeforbusiness/manage/health-and-monitoring/call-detail-recording-cdr) database, although that is not for "live" calls and the CDR database needs to be enabled for the site.  Once enabled you can just use SQL queries again the DB for historical call data.

If you really need large scale call monitoring, then the only option is to create a [SIP proxy application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lync/server-sdk/lync-server-2013-sdk-documentation) that runs on the FE machines and translates "sip" messages into call events.  This is a lot of work, it seems simple to do but gets very difficult very fast.  This will give you "live" call events but will take someone a long long time to get it right and you have to have a deep understanding of SIP.

If you are talking about just your local Skype desktop client calls ONLY (windows client only), you can use the [client SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lync/desktop/lync-2013-sdk-documentation) to hook into the local client and you can track the call events that way.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation! Using the busy status seems to be too vague and not suitable... I didn't know about CDR, but also not suitable since I need live data. I already thought about the SIP solution, but since I'm not familiar at all with SIP, this might be too complex, so looks like my best bet is to use the Client SDK after all (we only use Windows, so that's a plus). Do you have experience with the client SDK? How hard do you think it is to just write an app that does something like my pseudo code above?

Comment: I have done all of the above for lots of different reasons.  I would suggest that you use the presence solution.  If you need to track a number of users, I would suggest a UCMA trusted application setup as the "best" solution, if it's just a single person then it doesn't really matter what SDK you use.  The problem with the link client SDK is that it's old and has never been updated.  Since it is last release was for Lync 2013, it has been slowly breaking is certain areas (altho the presence area works fine).

Comment: Other problems with the Lync client SDK is that it it doesn't scale to a number of users, and only works on windows (so other Skype client's will be a void).  You can think of the Lync client SDK as a remote control API for the running Skype client on a users machine.  So if you app is not running on the users machine, you are blind.

Comment: I can't just use the presence state, because I need to know more info than that (e.g. what person is calling etc.). it would be perfectly fine if it's a client-based solution, even if it's just on windows. I could easily install my program on every client. So a skype remote control actually sounds good to me, as long as it let's me access all the information I need (e.g. "listen to call events")...

Comment: Yes the Lync Client SDK will do what you want.  For your use case it should be pretty easy to do.  See example here: https://blog.thoughtstuff.co.uk/2013/01/tracking-lync-conversations-in-code/